# Dirichlet Distribution in PyMC

Tags: python, distribution, pymc, mcmc, dirichlet

Can someone please explain working with a Dirichlet distribution in PyMC (with a working example) ?

I realize it is trivial but I am not able to find trace of all the components. Is there any way out ?

I have already posted the relevant part of my code here

[KeyError while printing trace in PyMC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092306/keyerror-while-printing-trace-in-pymc)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe what bothers you is that when you define a k-component Dirichlet distribution, pymc only gives k-1 components. The remaining component is assumed to be 1 minus the sum of all the components. See [here](https://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc/distributions.html#pymc.distributions.dirichlet_like).

By the way, this behaviour has changed in pymc3, and it returns the k components (which obviously add to 1).